# multiple indexes in XeLaTeX with xindy

Tags: xetex, indexing, xindy

the issue: I tried to make more than one index in XeLaTeX with xindy package, but I have not succeeded to make  it work. 
It must  be necessarily in  XeLaTeX  and, because I have two languages (english, greek)  to manage,  I thought that xindy  would give the desired result. 
Right below I give a minimal  example,   which unfortunately   doesn't work,   since only  the main index appears (after compile).
Any idea would be  appreciated.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Liberation Serif}
\setsansfont{Liberation Serif}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\makeindex[columns=2,title=Ευρετήριο όρων,intoc=true, options= -C utf8]
\makeindex[name=name,columns=2,title=Ευρετήριο ονομάτων,   intoc=true,options= -C utf8]

\begin{document}

Α\index{α}
Β\index{β}
Γ\index{γ}
Δ\index{δ}
Ε\index{ε}
Ζ\index{ζ}
Η\index{η}
Θ\index{θ}
Ι\index{ι}
Κ\index{κ}
Λ\index{λ}
a\index{a}
b\index{b}
c\index{c}
d\index{d}
e\index{e}
f\index{f}
g\index{g}
h\index{h}

Αρχιμήδης\index[name]{Αρχιμήδης}\\
Cantor\index[name]{Cantor}\\
Πλάτων\index[name]{Πλάτων}\\
Riemann\index[name]{Riemann}

\printindex

\printindex[name]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Did you run both texindy calls? (`texindy -C utf8 your-main-file.idx` and `texindy -C utf8 name.idx`)?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're correct! I'm new in XeLaTeX. In pdf+LaTeX this goes (almost) automatically. Thanks!

Comment: makeindex is in the list of "safe" applications, and so imakeidx can call it directly, but xindy has to be called by you (and so log-file tells you what to do).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Could you write up an answer to this?